# Is there any efficient way to get a large vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a vector with n elements inside(I mean the size not the capacity of the vector is n) but don't want to initialize any of them during creation because that's nothing but rubbish to me. Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Edit: All I can imagine is to use reserve(n) and do some hack(can somebody tell me how) to make the vector believe it has n elements. Or I just jump into a cesspit and dance with malloc and free.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to violate the RAII principle. What do you want to do with the memory of this vector?

Comment: What is the expected access pattern to the elements? (The short answer is no, but there might be a workaround.)

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense. If there is an actual element inside the vector, then that element HAS TO be initialized. Otherwise use reserve.

Comment: How would you want to use this vector?

Comment: There are valid reasons to want this.  For example, you might eventually populate every element in the vector, but not in the usual 0 .. n-1 order.

Comment: ... or even in order, but not via a constructor.

Comment: Here is an awesome trick I learned about recently that makes use of uninitialised memory safely: http://research.swtch.com/sparse

Comment: @Mike Will the vector be holding objects (class/struct), or just integral type (int,float,etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you construct a vector with the constructor taking a `size` parameter (and don't specify an element to copy into the vector), the elements will be *value-initialized*.  The rules for value initialization (8.5p7) specify that primitives are zero-initialized.

The only way round this is to wrap your primitive in a class type that defines a no-op default constructor:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    A() {};
    T value;
};

std::vector<A<int>> vec(1000);
```

If you can encapsulate the initialization process as an iterator, you could use the iterator to construct the vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec(it_begin, it_end);
```

Otherwise I'd recommend not worrying too much about the overhead of initialization; it's not going to change the complexity of your algorithm (since you'll be accessing each member anyway, which makes it O(n) already).

Comment: I wonder why it's specified to be value-initialized to 0 for primitives, seems horribly Java-ish to me. — But after all, proper RAII is better anyway. Also, I reckon the compiler can sometimes optimise away the pre-initialisation?

Comment: It might be a good idea to offer automatic conversion to and from `T`, so that using the `A<T>` type is less painful.  `A(T t) : value(t) {}` and `operator T&() { return value; } operator T const&() const { return value; }`, respectively. But knowing C++, this might cause an explosion down the road...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: "I wonder why it's specified to be value-initialized to 0 for primitives" Because it prevents stupidity. This is the same reason why you can't copy a `unique_ptr` and why `shared_ptr` exists. The `vector`'s actual contents must always be in a known state.

Comment: @NicolBolas: that's not comparable at all. `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are tools for specific jobs, which they fulfill in the obvious way, and they aren't _mandatory_: plain C-pointers are in almost every way equivalent, you just don't get the safety; it is assumed that C++ programmers know what they're doing, and that if they don't explicitly _say_ they want a safety net they aren't _forced_ to use one anyway even, though it may get in the way of what they want to do. That's what's great about C++.   On the other hand, `std::vector` has another specific job that's quite similar ...

Comment: ... to `unique_ptr`: providing safe memory management for not just one object, but a whole array. It's job is _not_ to care about the actual objects that the programmer stores in there. Just to give as convenient _access_ to them as possible, which also includes easy initialisation. If the programmer _wants_ a 0-initialised array, for safety reasons or whatever, they can just say so, it's trivially simple! But if you know you won't need it, you shouldn't be patronised. — 0-initialisation doesn't provide much safety anyway: if you forget the proper initialisation, it's hardly better to have ...

Comment: ... uninitialised fields with value zero than uninitialised fields with virtually random bogus values; in fact I'd say it's _worse_ because bogus values jump to the eye much quicker in a debug session. To get _real_ initialisation safety, you need more sophisticated language features, like a strong functional paradigm. — I apologise for the rant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an allocator which `construct` member is a no-op for e.g. trivially default constructible types. Be aware of what this entails* and you may want to profile and/or examine the generated code to make sure it's worth it.

*: assuming `vector_type` is a specialization of `std::vector` which uses such an allocator then `vector_type v(42); auto copy = v;` results in `copy` reading elements of `v` with unspecified values. This can easily go wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Use [std::vector::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/):

```
std::vector big_vec();
big_vec.reserve(100000);
```

Comment: -1 this doesn't affect the size, but capacity. **exactly** what he asked us not to do.

Comment: No, that's not what i want. As I said: the size not the capacity

Answer (score -3):

```
 int zeros[n*size(int)/size(T)];
 vector<T> big((T*)myints, (T*)myints + n);
```

Comment: This is just a contrived way of saying `vector<int> fifth(n);` with the added risk of a stack overflow.

Comment: @larsmans No the type of the vector is not `vector<int>`. I admit that I have to improve my answer in order to show the needed cast to T* if it is not implicitly convertible from int *. but this basically the only way to construct a vector with something else memory without constructing elements.

Comment: Still, you're zero-initializing `zeros`, which takes time. (Unless `n` is a compile-time constant, in which case using a `vector` is a strange idea.)

Comment: Well I was supposing the cost of constructing T was a problem, not memsetting a portion of memory. Anyway then we can just remove the 0 initialization, at the cost of really having garbage in the objets

Comment: @log0, won't `vector<T>::vector(Iter, Iter)` call `T::copy_ctor` for each "element" from source range? This is not much different from calling default constructors.

Comment: @Paul depends on your copy constructor

Comment: I mean, it will be called anyway, whether it's trivial or not. How is this different from calling default constructor (which also may be trivial)?

Comment: @Paul thats right. A constructor that does nothing is the best solution (If there is ever a problem). But if the OP cannot modify T, then the copy constructor will probably not do possible costly resource initialization.